# SetCenter problem for an UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uilabel

OK, I'm struggling to make this work but without success.
Basically I want to add a UILabel to an UIView and center it.

The code looks like this:

```
UIView *customTitleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
[customTitleView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

// Screen title
CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(200.0, 44.0f);
CGSize size = [screenTitle sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0] 
                      constrainedToSize:constraint 
                          lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap];

UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height)];
[titleLabel setText:screenTitle];
[titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0]];
[titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

titleLabel.center = customTitleView.center;

[customTitleView addSubview:titleLabel];
[titleLabel release];

self.navigationItem.titleView = customTitleView;
[customTitleView release];
```

I expected that the UILabel would be centered within the UIView.
Well, it isn't. It is somehow right aligned and not even close to the center of the UIView.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just tried using your code verbatim and it's working correctly for me (label is correctly centered in view). Perhaps something else is interfering with it?

Comment: Ooops, I forgot to mention that the custom UIView will replace the titleView property from the top navigation bar. I will update the posted code.

Comment: try 
    `UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(customTitleView.frame.size.width/2-size.width/2, 
                                                                customTitleView.frame.size.height/2-size.height/2, 
                                                                size.width, 
                                                                size.height)];`  
to init the titleLabel

Comment: Nope, still offseted to the right ... like I said, not even close to the center.

Comment: Well, have you tried `titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:customTitleView.bounds]; titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;`?

Comment: Yes, that was one of the first things I tried. Obviously, didn't work. Check Erik B's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what's going wrong:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = customTitleView;
```

When you set `customTitleView` as the title view of the navigation item the frame of `customTitleView` will change. `customTitleView` won't be 320 pixels wide anymore, but the frame of `titleLabel` will remain the same. Thus it will no longer be centered.

Can't you just set `titleLabel` as `titleView`? I think it should be centered automatically. If not, I know a more complicated way to solve it. Drop a comment and I'll tell you how.

**EDIT:** So here is how you realign the `titleLabel` after `customTitleView`'s frame has changed.

When the frame of a view is changed `layoutSubviews` is called on that view. So instead of letting `customTitleView` be a regular `UIView` you need to make it a custom view that inherits from `UIView`. In that custom view you override `layoutSubviews` and in your implementation of `layoutSubviews` you make sure everything is aligned the way you want based on the new frame (`self.frame`). I'll leave the implementation to you.

Comment: Thanks for clearing what the issue is. The thing is that titleLabel is not the only view that needs to stay on the top nav bar. I still have two buttons right aligned. But indeed, if I directly set titleLabel as titleView, then yes it is centered by default.

Comment: @TeodorC If you're using `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` and/or `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Erik self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem sets only 1 button, right? If I have 2 buttons one after the other then I can't use self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.

Comment: @TeodorC Are you saying that you add those buttons to `customTitleView`?

Comment: @Erik Yeah, this is exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: @TeodorC Then I think you should have included that code as well. May I ask why you have two right aligned buttons in the nav bar? As an iPhone user I find that very odd.

Comment: @TeodorC If you decide not to revise the UI-design (which you definitely should consider), may I ask if you're able to align the buttons properly?

Comment: @ Erik B I'm not currently near my Mac but you have a point regarding the UI-design. I will use one button with self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem, but I'm still curious if by chance I will be forced to add another button along side the one implemented with self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem. What then? I will have to set a custom titleView property and I will still have the issue with the misaligned titleLabel ...

Comment: @TeodorC If it will make you accept my answer I will tell you how to realign `titleLabel` after `customTitleView`'s frame have changed.

Comment: @Erik B So layoutSubviews is the method that I should override and realign the titleLabel within customTitleView. Thanks for the tip.